# Linq to xml with missing nodes in the source XML and null-coalescing operator won't work

Tags: xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to parse an XML file into an XDocument and having trouble when nodes are missing. I can't seem to use the null-coalescing operator because I'm trying to parse the results into a list, so I get the compile-time error: Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' and 'string' from the following code:

```
movies = (from item in doc.Root.Elements("item")
          select new Movie
          {
              Title = (string)item.Element("title"),
              IMDB_Id = ((string)item.Element("imdb_id")),
              Actors = (from a in item.Element("actors").Elements("item")
                        select (string)a).ToList() ?? ""
```

So normally there are multiple Actors nodes that get read into my list:

```
<actor>
    <item>Matt Damon</item>
    <item>Ryan Gosling</item>
</actor
```

but when there is no actor node I get an error, so I tried to convert the null result to string (""), but that doesn't work because I get the error above. So how can I parse this document knowing that not all of the nodes will be present every time I read the file?

Comment: How does `Movie` class look like?

Comment: The movie class looks like this:  public class Movie
    {
        public List<string> Actors { get; set; }   public string IMDB_Id { get; set; }      public string Title { get; set; }

Answer (score 0):

How about using `let` keyword and prepare dummy, empty `actors` element when it does not exist?

```
movies = (from item in doc.Root.Elements("item")
          let actorsElement = item.Element("actors") ?? new XElement("actors")
          select new Movie
          {
              Title = (string)item.Element("title"),
              IMDB_Id = ((string)item.Element("imdb_id")),
              Actors = (from a in actorsElement.Elements("item")
                                     select (string)a).ToList()
```

Comment: Marcin - I put in the code exactly as you suggested above and I get a "Method Name Expected" compiler error on actorsElement in the `Actors = actorsElement(...` line. Any idea how to fix this or another way around the original problem?

Comment: Updated my answer. Check it now.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues:

1. `ToList()` returns an empty list if there are no actors, not `null` as you seem to expect.
2. You're getting that `Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' and 'string'` error because if the list is not `null` a list will be returned, but otherwise a string will be returned. The compiler won't let you do that because C# is strongly typed. You can't assign a list to a string or vice versa.
3. In fact, you don't need the nullable operator: you know when there are no actors when `Actors` is an empty list. Check this with `Actors.Count() == 0` or `!Actors.Any()`.

I'd suggest ditching the nullable operator, changing it to this:

```
Actors = (from a in item.Element("actors").Elements("item")
          select a.ToString()).ToList();
```

Alternatively:

```
Actors = item.Element("actors").Elements("item")
         .Select(a => a.ToString()).ToList();
```

Comment: It will throw `NullReferenceException` when `<actors>` element does not exist.

Comment: Yeah, so will his. I decided not to go on a long tangent about checking for `null` all over the place so I could keep my answer short. Very good point, though!